# how to use python requests get all of the response?

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

With this code

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

link = "http://sp.kaola.com/api/category/goods?pageNo=1&pageSize=20&search=%7B%0A%20%20%22sortType%22%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%20%3A%200%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22isNavigation%22%20%3A%20%220%22%2C%0A%20%20%22filterTypeList%22%20%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%20%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%204055%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%20%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22category%22%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22parentCategoryId%22%20%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22categoryId%22%20%3A%204055%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%22source%22%20%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%22noStoreCount%22%20%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%22isActivity%22%20%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%22storeCount%22%20%3A%2060%0A%7D"
df = reqeusts.get(link).json()
print df
```

I can get the response for the URL I'm querying.

But how can I get the data from when the url's GET arg becomes pageNo = 3, 4 and so on?
I want get all of the responses from all the pages in one request. If this possible ?

In each page I can get 20 responses. How can I get all of them ?

update：

i use this method to clearn the json：

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df1 = df['body']
df_final = json_normalize(df1['result'],'goodsList')
```

HOW CAN I  get all the response into only one dataframe?

Comment: Your question is very unclear to me, please explain more

Answer (score 0):

Getting all the responses on one page doesn't seem possible. This is something you cannot control, and only the person who made the website can control.

But, what you can do is loop through the pages of the search result and add them together. I notice you have a `hasMore` variable which tells if there are more search results. This gives something like this:

```
import requests

link = "http://sp.kaola.com/api/category/goods?pageSize=20&search=%7B%0A%20%20%22sortType%22%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%20%3A%200%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22isNavigation%22%20%3A%20%220%22%2C%0A%20%20%22filterTypeList%22%20%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%20%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%204055%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%20%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22category%22%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22parentCategoryId%22%20%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22categoryId%22%20%3A%204055%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%22source%22%20%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%22noStoreCount%22%20%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%22isActivity%22%20%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%22storeCount%22%20%3A%2060%0A%7D"
max_pages = 100
data = {}

for page_no in range(max_pages):
    try:
        req = reqeusts.get(link + "&pageNo=" + str(page_no))
    except reqeusts.ConnectionError:
        break # Stop loop if the url was not found.

    df = req.json()
    if df["body"]["result"]["hasMore"] == 0:
        break # Page says it has no more results

    # Here, add whatever data you want to save from df to data
```

Comment: The json you're getting is very messy - lots of data which is not in a tabular format (which is what data frames like). That depends on what data you want saved and what structure of the data frame you want